# Why just using a answer instead of a comment lead to downvotes

Tags: discussion

I wanted to asked a user with his/her question, but because I didn't have enough reputation to leave a comment, I used a answer instead.

And when I did that, my answer have 3 downvotes immediately.

Why? (I did say that I don't have enough reputation in my answer)

P.s I get the "Peer Pressure" from this so...

Comment: Comments aren't answers, and not having enough rep to comment isn't an excuse to post an answer. you're two rep away from being able to comment: go edit one post and you can leave proper comments instead of abusing the answer section

Comment: @Zoe I did say that I will delete or edit the answer, and I'm not that good at English either.

Comment: Doesn't matter - you shouldn't post it in the first place. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Just imagine: There are close to 10,000 new posts every day. If a majority of those posts end-up as non-"answers" on various questions and we would do nothing, what would this site look like tomorrow, in a week, or in 6 to 8 weeks? You might not care but I assume you got interested in this site due to the valuable content you find here. There is a reason this site is so awesome, its strict rules are the basis of its success. Look at and use Quora or Yahoo! Answers if you prefer a more relaxed or even no moderation. You won't be bothered by anyone there, what ever you post.

Comment: @justANewbie - You should be aware of the fact, that by deleting an answer, it still counts against your ability to submit new answers.  Instead you should edit your answer, and actually answer the question, this will allow those users who downvoted your answer to reverse their vote.  Commentary submitted as answer to a question does not help the community.  If you continue to do this with other questions you answer, you will continue to get downvotes, and that action will result in an answer ban (automatically initiated to prevent additional commentary answers).

Comment: Been on meta for some time... Still waiting to see a complain "I provided good answer to a question and for some reason it was up-voted - why this site is so strange?" everyone complains "I did not provide an answer at all - why it is not upvoted"... I request more variety :)

Comment: Because we want answers and not chit-chat. For chit-chat, first create some (upvoted) answers. But you already have 50 rep, so you can post comments anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An answer to a question should be just that, an answer to the question.  Comments do not belong in an answer.  In fact, there's a "not an answer" flag that can be applied to such an answer.

You need at least 50 reputation to comment on another user's post.  You're almost there, so once you reach that level you'll be able to comment.